# AngularJS $location.path(url) not Redirecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, location

All,

I have an AngularJS PhoneGap app I am working on. I am stuck on one redirect that occurs immediately after receiving an API call response. My code is located at [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/bp4151/277795cf61f3f7c721f9)

My issue is on line 300 of controllers.js, where I am calling my redirect within a then() block.

```
UserService.login($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
            .then(function(response) {

                globals.session_id = response.data.meta.session_id;
                globals.logged_in_userId = response.data.response.users[0].id;

                if ($scope.user.remember === true) {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("_session_id", response.data.meta.session_id);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("logged_in_userId", response.data.response.users[0].id);
                } else {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem("_session_id");
                    window.localStorage.removeItem("logged_in_userId");
                }
            })
            .then(function() {
                $location.path("/tab/locations");// <=== This line doesn't cause an error but does not result in a redirect
            })
            .
        catch (function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
```

If anyone could please help me out, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: So far I've tried using rootScope apply, scope apply, and using a variable inside the promise return along with scope watch, and at no time does the redirect work. I have also tried using window.navigation.href, and I still get nothing. 

There has to be a way to redirect the user after successfully logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue was actually in my app.js run function call. On location change it looks at a global variable to see if a username has been set yet, and if not, it intercepts the call to send the client to the login page. Once I moved my code inside the OnLocationChange handler to look at the variable there, it redirected properly.

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 7):

Try $rootScope.$apply(); after $location.path()

OR

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $location.path("/tab/locations");
});
```

You can also use $location.url()

Comment: Hi Abhishek

Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I have tried both approaches with no luck.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `then` handler needs to return something so that the promise will be stilled resolve for the next condition.

Just add `return response` at the end of your `then` handlers.

Comment: Hi Alp, 

Thanks for your reply. I just tried that but still get no redirect.

Comment: does it work if you use `window.location.href = "/tab/locations"`?